# Create a copy of UIImageView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to be able to call a function and have that function create a copy of a `UIImageView`. This is where I construct the image I want to be copied.

```
    var redBar = UIImageView()
    let redBarImage = UIImage(named: "Music Bar")
    redBar = UIImageView(image: redBarImage)
    self.addSubview(redBar)
```

When the user does a pan gesture (this part I have done), I want to call a function called "produceRedBar" like this:

```
func produceRedBar(){
}
```

The `redBar` is a global variable. How can I produce a copy of the `redBar`, but it needs to produce a new copy every time the function is called.

Comment: why do you want to create a copy every time??

Comment: @satheeshwaran here is my design: http://imgur.com/XHMBUdj . I want to the user to be able to pan upward and add those red bars. one on top of the other. When they pan downward, they should hide on after the other

Comment: @satheeshwaran can you help me my man? Am I approaching this correctly? If so, how can i copy it everytime the function is called?

Comment: Why do you have to copy the image view buddy? Create new ones for each of the bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying image views etc why don't you try this,

```
func produceRedBar(value: Int){

    for i in 0...value{
        let newView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Music Bar"))
        var rectImage:CGRect = newView.frame
        rectImage.origin.x = 10
        rectImage.origin.y = CGFloat(10 + (i * 20) + 5) //10 - origin + i * 20 - for placing + 5 - padding
        self.view.addSubview(newView)
    }

}
```

and call your produceRedBar() method with the count of the volume value like this,

```
self.produceRedBar(5)
self.produceRedBar(4)
self.produceRedBar(6)
```

Note: adjust x and y values accordingly.

Comment: Gotcha, so do i not have to create a copy? Because in your case you create a UIImageView called "newView" and add it to the subview only once, it won't produce 10, no matter the value in the for loop correct?

Comment: yes but the loop would execute 10 times adding ten UIImageView objects to self. This should do it.

Comment: If i want to add just one at a time, i don't need to do a for loop correct?

Comment: hmmm yes but it is better to run the loop every time to adjust the volume figure.